# Installing gstreamer version 1.14 instead of expected 1.20

Tags: ubuntu, package, gstreamer, apt

Im on Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to install gstreamer with

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

yelds version 1.14:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.14.0
GStreamer 1.14.0
Unknown package origin
```

Altough I expected 1.20:

```
apt-show-versions libgstreamer1.0-dev
libgstreamer1.0-dev:amd64/jammy-updates 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 uptodate


sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libgstreamer1.0-dev is already the newest version (1.20.3-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

It is a third Ubuntu fresh installation that Im trying to install gstreamer. Previous time on the same pc I got 1.20 version with same steps. Once on other pc I got 1.14 or 1.16, I dont recall. How can I get 1.20 version and what could be the reasons Im getting old version of the package?

Here is `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

EDIT:
I think I figured what happened. I firstly installed Anaconda3 distribution, which comes with gstreamer old version package. And after that I install gstreamer via apt. But I get to use Anaconda version instead of apt. Not sure how to work around that beside removing Anaconda distribution.

Comment: I think this must be a fluke. There is no ambiguity in debian packages in ubuntu. The ubuntu 22 repo doesn't even contain these old versions of gstreamer. I suspect your apt sources are messed up. Can you post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?